# C# parse JSON to listview?

Tags: xamarin

Ho can deserialize this json to listview of xamarin

I try to make a simple deserilize but nohing

```
{
"1": {
    "Category": "IT",
    "DateB": "Mon, 20 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
    "Description": "asdads",
    "ProductName": "test2",
    "Price": 123,
    "ProductD": false,
    "id": 1
},
"2": {
    "Category": "Shop",
    "DateB": "Mon, 20 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
    "Description": "asdads",
    "ProductName": "test123132",
    "Price": 123,
    "ProductD": false,
    "id": 2
}
```

}

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, @Generazione di domani. In order for us to be able to help you with your issue, we would need from you to show us what have you tried and what is preventing you from succeeding.

Comment: why do you use this json data and why not use this format:[{
 "Category": "IT",
 "DateB": "Mon, 20 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
 "Description": "asdads",
 "ProductName": "test2",
 "Price": 123,
 "ProductD": false,
 "id": 1
}, {
 "Category": "Shop",
 "DateB": "Mon, 20 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
 "Description": "asdads",
 "ProductName": "test123132",
 "Price": 123,
 "ProductD": false,
 "id": 2
}]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON to C# model using [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) :

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DateB")]
    public string DateB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProductName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Price")]
    public long Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProductD")]
    public bool ProductD { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Product> FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Product>>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this Dictionary<string, Product> self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}
}
```

And after create ListView with ViewCell and ViewModel. In this case, ViewModel will include properties from the product model.